# How i can specify the number of extracted colors in a image with color-thief javascript library?

Tags: javascript, color-thief

I want to extract the color of a photo but extract if is posible 26 color, one color for every alphabet letter for a grapheme-color synesthesia ebook reader experiment.

Thanks!